# Google Maps Marker Clusterer and info window

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, markerclusterer

I have the following code to try to get the MarkerClusterer library to work for my Google Map, it's work. But when i try to close all info window by click on map, my info window on clusterer don't work.
See my work here : http://www.concepteur-internet.fr/test_carto1.php
Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
                //infowindow.close();
             });
```

To:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
                infowindow.close();
             });
```

Comment: it is precisely when I put it that bug, the infowindows on clusterer no works !

Comment: You can see the result of `infowindow.close();` here : [link]http://www.concepteur-internet.fr/test_carto2.php

Comment: The clusterclick is propagating to the map.  Have you tried [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)? It doesn't seem to have that problem, [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_markerclustererplus_examples_simple_exampleA.html).